Why are permissions not being overridden for a viewset?
I have created a viewset for authentication. Since this is the authentication viewset, I want this viewset to be accessible to unauthorized users as well. Following DRF documentation, this is what I have:
class AuthenticationViewSet(viewsets.ViewSet):
    permission_classes = [AllowAny]

    def create_user(self, request: Request) -> Response:
        #code for creating a user

Since I want the other viewsets to be accessible only to the authorized users, I set the following in settings.py:
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    "DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES": ["rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated"],
    "DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES": [
        "authentication.token_auth.ExpiringTokenAuthentication"
    ]
}

When I make an API call to the create_user endpoint, I get an error saying: "No token found".
Why is this happening? Shouldn't the permissions be overridden based on the permission_classes list in the viewset?
For reference, my authentication class:
class ExpiringTokenAuthentication(TokenAuthentication):
    def authenticate(self, request):
        if COOKIE_KEY in request.COOKIES:
            token_key = request.COOKIES[COOKIE_KEY]
        else:
            raise exceptions.AuthenticationFailed("No token found")

        try:
            token = Token.objects.get(key=token_key)
        except Token.DoesNotExist:
            return exceptions.AuthenticationFailed("Invalid token")

        if isTokenExpired(token):
            raise exceptions.AuthenticationFailed("Token has expired")

        user = token.user

        return (user, token)


def isTokenExpired(token):
    currentTime = datetime.now(datetime.UTC)
    currentTimeUTC = currentTime.replace(tzinfo=pytz.UTC)
    return token.created < currentTimeUTC - timedelta(hours=TOKEN_EXPIRE_HOURS)



Took me a lot longer than it should have to figure this out. But you have to add both permission_classes=[] and authentication_classes=[] in the viewset, if you want to allow unrestricted access to a viewset.
Authentication and permissions are two different concepts in DRF. Authentication is to figure out who the user is. Permissions is to figure out if the authenticated user is allowed to perform the requested action.
In this case, while I was bypassing the permissions by setting permission_classes=[], I was still getting the 401 because the request was not coming from an authenticated user, as DRF was checking the request to figure who was making the request.
So the code for the viewset becomes:
class AuthenticationViewSet(viewsets.ViewSet):
    permission_classes = []
    authentication_classes = []

    def create_user(self, request: Request) -> Response:
        # code for creating a user


